# Euler-Lagrange equations without lower boundary conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

Could someone help me with the following problem?

Let be the functional $F(y)=\int_a^bf(t,y,y')$, ($f\in{C^2[a,b]\times{\mathbb{R}}\times{\mathbb{R}}}$) with $y\in{C^2[a,b]}$ and
$y(b)=0$, prove that if we have a extreme, $y^*$, of that functional with these conditions then $\delta_{y'}f(a,y^*(a),y'^*(a))=0$.

Comment: What is $\delta_{y'}$?

Comment: Derivative in the direction y'

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Define momentum 
   $$p~:=~\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}.\tag{1}$$ 
   If one varies infinitesimally the functional 
   $$F[y]~:=~ \int_a^b\! dt~ f(t,y(t),y^{\prime}(t)) \tag{2}$$ 
   *without* discarding boundary contributions, one finds
   $$ \delta F[y]~=~  \int_a^b\! dt~\left( \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial y(t)}\delta y(t)+p(t) ~\delta y^{\prime}(t)\right)$$
   $$~\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{=}~  
   p(b)~\underbrace{\delta y(b)}_{=0}- p(a)~\delta y(a)+  \int_a^b\! dt~\left( \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial y(t)}-\frac{d p(t)}{dt}\right) \delta y(t)
   .\tag{3}$$
2. Besides the given boundary condition $y(b)=0$, one concludes from formula (3) that a stationary configuration must obey 
   $$ p(a)~=~0\quad\text{and} \quad\forall t\in [a,b]: \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial y(t)}-\frac{d p(t)}{dt}~=~0.\tag{4}$$